# Typescript object specific prop with key in

Tags: typescript

Is it posssible to use one property with specific type when using key in of type?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=3&ssc=67&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAsghgOxABQE4HswGcoF4oDkCcAthAVAD6FwDm5AUA6JLCAPIBGAVnlAN4BtANYQQUAJYJYiFBmwBdAFxQEAVxKcIqADRQ4AEwMTgE9MQA2aTAH4VWYKim0AvkA).

```
type ManyProps = 'name' | 'age' | 'height'

type MyObj = {[key in ManyProps]: number, name?: string}
```

Comment: To make all props optional you should wrap it in Partial: type MyObj = Partial<Record<Exclude<ManyProps, 'age'>, string> & { age: number }>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [exclude](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludetu) the name property and include it after

```
type MyObj = Record<Exclude<ManyProps, 'name'>, number> & { name?: string }
```

Comment: thanks, is there a way to make all props optional with record?

Comment: @RTW my bad wrong link, https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialt

Comment: heh, i was confused :)

Answer (score 2):

There might be a simpler way than this, but you could always use an intersection:

```js
type ManyProps = 'name' | 'age' | 'height';

type MyObj = { [key in ManyProps]: number } & { otherName?: string };
```

Comment: it's doesn't work: type ManyProps = 'name' | 'age' | 'height';

type MyObj = { [key in ManyProps]?: number } & { name: string } ;

function fn(): MyObj{
    return {
        age: 10,
        name: 'sss'
    }
}

Comment: Ah, that's because we're reusing the same key. Updating the answer.

Comment: @casiebar, thanks anyway, but i need same property :) Updated answer to make it clear